# How to add gallery functionality to WordPress block plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm wanting to add gallery functionality to a WP Gutenberg block plugin.  Easy to add a single image option with the media library, but I'm not sure how I would add the element for a gallery which then gives you all the built in WordPress functionality of caption and drag/drop sorting of the gallery.  Having a real hard time finding a tutorial on including this functionality.

I did find one plugin that does just about what I want as the base, but want to extend the block to include other fields.  Plugin in question is [getwid](https://wordpress.org/plugins/getwid/) slider block.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Needed to add addToGallery=true and gallery=true to the mediaupload tag.

```js
<MediaUpload
          addToGallery={true}
                 onSelect={(media) => {setAttributes({images: [...images, ...media]});}}
                 type="image"
                 multiple={true}
                 gallery={true}
                 value={images}
                 render={({open}) => (
                     <Button className="slider-button select-images-button is-button is-default is-large" onClick={open}>
                         Add images
                     </Button>
                 )}
             />
```